# Postman returning FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, on inserting PlatformEventChannelMember

Tags: json, tooling-api, platform-event, postman

In this trailhead: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/create-a-custom-channel-and-enrich-change-events/add-a-channel-member-and-configure-change-event-enrichment

I'm trying to add a Channel member. So saving the channel was fine. With Postman, i sent:

POST URL: {{_endpoint}}/services/data/v{{version}}/tooling/sobjects/PlatformEventChannel

Body:

```
{
  "FullName": "SalesEvents_AccountChangeEvent",
  "Metadata": {
    "enrichedFields": [
      {
        "name": "External_Account_ID__c"
      },
      {
        "name": "Industry"
      }
    ],
    "eventChannel": "SalesEvents__chn",
    "selectedEntity": "AccountChangeEvent"
  }
}
```

Seems to work, because i go back:

```
{
    "id": "0YL09000000XZBKGA4",
    "success": true,
    "errors": [],
    "warnings": [],
    "infos": []
}
```

Then i need to add a member. So from:

POST URL: {{_endpoint}}/services/data/v{{version}}/tooling/sobjects/PlatformEventChannelMember

Body:

```
{
  "FullName": "SalesEvents_AccountChangeEvent",
  "Metadata": {
    "enrichedFields": [
      {
        "name": "External_Account_ID__c"
      },
      {
        "name": "Industry"
      }
    ],
    "eventChannel": "SalesEvents__chn",
    "selectedEntity": "AccountChangeEvent"
  }
}
```

the error is

```
[
    {
        "message": "The selected field, External_Account_ID__c, isn't valid.",
        "errorCode": "FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION",
        "fields": []
    }
]
```

The weird thing is, the format and steps seem to be ok, given they are the same as this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_enrich_tooling_api.htm

Any ideas?